# QGIS - Holes added to a point shapefile in the attribute table not displaying

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, csv, attribute-joins

I have a point shapefile with ~300 points stored holding, x,y,z data and three other variables.

I needed to add another 20 points to the existing shapefile. To do this I conducted a join with a CSV that held the data for the additional 20 points. The data i.e. point ID's, x,y,z info for the new points now show up in the attribute table for my shapefile however the points themselves are not plotting on my workspace.

I have saved and re-imported the updated shapefile to no avail. I have also tried loading the shapefile in another 'blank' workspace to no result. The coordinate system for the shapefile is correct and there are no CRS conflicts within the workspace.

Comment: Make Sure that you mark x, y as a geometry while adding csv. If you don't do that it will be only nonspatial table

Comment: Yes, this was done when the CSV was imported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i understand you correct you only joined the points to your shapefile. But to have the points with their coordinates integrated into the shapefile you have to append them. The attributtable is not used to draw the geometries as they are stored in another part of the shape-file (as binary in the .shp).

When you have your points loaded you can select all the new points and copy them (ctrl+c or via the "Edit"-menue) and paste them into your shape-file layer (ctrl+v). Just make sure to have the right layer activated when you copy and then activate the one where you want to paste into.

Comment: Thank you. I never even stopped to think that it could be as simple as a copy past process. Your method works perfectly.

As a side not however if I add points into a shapefile attribute table is there a way to force the shapefile to 're-draw' the geometries thus plotting any data added directly to the attribute table?